# Symfony2 console command in a dependent bundle

Tags: php, symfony, console, command

I've developed a bundle, which is not a standalone Symfony2 application, but merely a layer between the framework and the final application, taking care of some common taks.

When I create a Bundle/Command/SomeCommand.php with an appropriate class within, the command isn't available in Symfony. When I, however, copy the same command to the "final" bundle, which extends upon classes from the "parent" bundle, the command is available there.

I suspect the bundle has to be registered somewhere in Kernel or such thing, but I'm struggling to find any information about that, so any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can register your commands as services. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/commands_as_services.html . Or you could add a MyUtilBundle class to your Bundle directory and include it in your AppKernel.  That will automatically register any commands in the Commands directory.

Comment: Have you registered both bundles in `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: That was the actual issue, thanks! I used to struggle with having the bundle in AppKernel, when it was also defined in application's parameters.yml components section. However, the dependent bundle (MyUtilBundle as Cerad describes it) has no issue being in the AppKernel, so once I've added it there, it works great!

Answer (score 1):

When `Bundle` is registered as a bundle, the command should be available when it's placed in `Bundle/Command/SomeCommand.php` (note the singular `Command` versus your plural form).

You can also tag it as a service since Symfony 2.4, you can register commands as services using the `console.command` tag.

Comment: Let me add that service commands are registered in a compiler pass: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddConsoleCommandPass.php. In a similar way you could register your commands automatically, by looking into specific directories. Bundle commands are registered by each of the bundles in the registerCommands method: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/Bundle.php#L172. It simply looks into the Command folder.

Comment: Thanks, the plural/singular issue was just when I was typing it over here, thanks for pointing it out though!